# Magento Customer Login and Account Creation content is not displaying

Tags: php, magento

I have been working on a magento projects for some months now. So I have added my custom online payment integration.

After adding payment integration the content on all the page disappears leaving only the header and the footer. I have now recover the page that I can access back-end through cms->page but the login and registering a new customer account page cannot be done from the back-end.

Thanks

Comment: try to disable that payment extension and check

Comment: This would be my guess - something in your layout updates for the payment module is over-riding the default